# Why is it so that if some bitcoin is spent by any user, the rest of his account's amount should also be spent and paid him back?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I guess this is called Circular spending.

Why is it required in the bitcoin protocol?

Answer (score 1):

Because on the lowest level of bitcoin protocol there is no accounts. There are scripts inside transaction. The most common script says: show me public key, I will compute Hash160 of it, compare with given Hash160, and if they are equal, I will check signature.

Let imagine, transaction contains single output with 1 bitcoin. Script contains Hash160 (which we treat as account). There is no way to spent part of bitcoin. We have to spent entire output, which is equal to 1 BTC in our case.
Transactions, like blocks, form some kind of chain.

Comment: thanks for the answer! if you can share any documentation about this, that wud b very helpful

Comment: You can use official wiki: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Transaction_Verification https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script